# Отображение кода в MS Word c подсветкой синтаксиса

Tags: ms-word, синтаксис

Может знает кто, как такое можно реализовать? Все коды в Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вам хватит вот [этого](http://highlight.hohli.com/)

Из эклипса туда, оттуда через IE (тогда "цвет" сохранится) в ворд.

Или вам нужно более "потоковое" решение?

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: vim, Emacs умеют делать подсвеченный код в формате html.